# Angularjs: How to include empty option in select when using ng-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, html-select

How can I add empty option in the beginning when I use ng-option to provide predefined list of options which doesn't include empty one?

An example in jade

```
select(ng-model="property.Value", ng-options="item.Value as item.Name for item in property.Choices")
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just add an option with empty value inside of the select.

```
select(ng-model="property.Value", ng-options="item.Value as item.Name for item in property.Choices")
  option(value="")
```

Here's an example - http://jsfiddle.net/sseletskyy/uky9m/1/

Comment: What if the data comes from a services for example? Besides that I generally try to avoid view-specific things in the controller. It would be great if there was a way to do that in the view. Maybe using a directive?!

Comment: not working if you choose an option and then like to change back to empty option.

Comment: @dang please provide an example when it doesn't work
e.g. here is my another example - http://codepen.io/sseletskyy/pen/KzYaQq

Comment: @SergeSeletskyy dang is referring to the fiddle you provided, the first example with the "Show empty option by default" cannot be changed back to blank

Answer (score 1):

just modify the property.choices array in angular.

> $scope.property.Choices.splice(0, 0, {"id":"0","Name":"Richard"});

Answer (score 1):

This just worked for me by modifying the object

angular.extend({'Please Select' : ''},objectName)