# Empty element in Angular ng-options (with and without grouping)

Tags: angularjs

I have (a seemingly common) problem with empty option values an angular model viewed using a select using ng-options.

```
$scope.groupTypeOptions = [
    { group: 'g1', name: '---', value: null }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
];

<select ng-model='form.groupType' required ng-options='option.value as option.name group by option.group for option in groupTypeOptions'></select>
```

A fiddle can be seen here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v6z3zh49/

My goal is to, from a predefined model, show a grouped select with the selected item representing null (or empty string). However, when selecting a value and I always end up with an extra, empty, option element being added. See fiddle above.

I have looked at similar questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654631/why-does-angularjs-include-an-empty-option-in-select) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650315/angularjs-how-to-include-empty-option-in-select-when-using-ng-option), but cannot find a solution.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$scope.groupTypeOptions = [
        { group: 'g1', name: '---', value: undefined }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Feature', value: 'feature' }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Bug', value: 'bug' }, 
    { group: 'g2', name: 'Enhancement', value: 'enhancement' }
    ];
```

It happens because in javascript `null !== undefined`.

Hope, it will help.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ababashka/skk4uj1y/

Comment: THANK YOU! That really bugged me, very nice catch! Additional question: why doesn't the "track by" expression seem to work? See updated example at http://jsfiddle.net/ynb09mdb/

The manual at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select seems to indicate that the
    "select as label group by group for value in array track by trackexpr"
syntax should work?

Comment: @Victor: Hi, you are welcome with my answer) About your another question about `track by` - the thing is, you just can't combine `value as label for collection` with `track by`. You can see an angular issue https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564 and explanation in the comments from `janv` on 8'th of Aug.